# How to save the "user agent" in the Drupal logs?

Tags: 7

when going through the log files it would be really helpful to know if an error was caused by a real user or by a bot.

Is there a way to save the "user agent" string (browser name) to the drupal log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [hook_watchdog](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7), you can manipulate all, or some of your log messages. You can find the user agent string in the super-global [$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). This way you could for example prepend all "notices" with the user-agent, and all errors with both user-agent and remote IP.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that there's no guarantee on the level of truth of the user-agent as it's really easy to change for a bot creator (and a browser user as well). Thus, depending on the type of bot and whats its owner is trying to do, you might or might not be able to see if it's a bot just using the User-agent.

Typically, when I try to emulate a real average user through a script, I make sure my bot looks like a Firefox user as much as possible but on the other hand, when a crawling bot (such as the Google bots) visits your website, I think it tries to be identied as a Google bot.

Then, depending on what you want to detect, user-agent might or might not be what you should look for.